# AMPscript question - need precise syntax to show copy dynamically

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to write a bit of AMPscript that does the following:

IF firstname exists say "John, your"

IF no firstname say "Your"

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

%%=iif(empty(@firstName),"Your", concat(propercase(@firstName, "your")))=%%

I know it's a simple answer, help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
%%[
set @Firstname = Propercase[Fristname]
If empty(@Firstname) then
set @Firstname = "Your"
endif
]%%
```

Then you can use `@Firstname` wherein you want show the name, for example: 
`%%=v(@Firstname)=%%` is "your"